# Moshell tool installation on Docker Alpine

Tags: dockerfile, alpine-linux

I tried to install Moshell on Alpine, earlier there was a Moshell installation on Ubuntu. Now, I created a docker file based on Alpine Linux and it was replaced with the original `Dockerfile` based on Ubuntu. I have to make changes in the newly created docker file so that it will install the shell without any errors. The newly created docker file is like below:

```
FROM alpine:3.13

# Install tools and dependencies
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache curl file vim python3 net-tools openssh zip openjdk11-jre perl bash shadow

# Get group ID and group name from the host machine
ARG GROUP_ID 
ARG GROUP_NAME

# Copy installation files to the docker container
COPY moshell* /.mosh_inst/

# Install Moshell (full installation, default options)
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo -e "0\n/opt\n\n\n\n" | bash /.mosh_inst/moshell_install"]

# Create a new user (with the same username as the host)
RUN addgroup -g ${GROUP_ID} ${GROUP_NAME}
WORKDIR / EXPOSE 25 9002-9999 10000-11000 11881
```

The original `Dockerfile` is below:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Install tools and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y curl file vim python3 net-tools ssh zip openjdk-11-jre-headless

# Get group id and group name from the host machine
ARG GROUP_ID
ARG GROUP_NAME

# Copy installation files to the docker container
COPY moshell* /.mosh_inst/
WORKDIR /.mosh_inst

# Install Moshell (Full installation, default options)
RUN ["/bin/bash","moshell_install","-p","moshelldir=/opt,java=java,perl=/bin/perl"]

# Create a new user (with the same username as the host)
RUN addgroup --gid ${GROUP_ID} ${GROUP_NAME}

WORKDIR /

EXPOSE 25
EXPOSE 9002:9999
EXPOSE 10000:11000
EXPOSE 11881
```

The docker command execution:

```
docker build -t moshell24.0b_image /home/egajash/moshell24.0b/moshell/examples/docker/ 
WARNING: No output specified with docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load 

[+] Building 30.1s (3/3) FINISHED 
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile 0.0s 

=> => transferring dockerfile: 723B 0.0s 

=> ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.13 30.0s 

=> [auth] library/alpine:pull token for registry-1.docker.io 0.0s

[internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.13:

Dockerfile:2
1 | # Base image is Alpine Linux 
2 | >>> FROM alpine:3.13 
3 | 
4 | # Install tools and dependencies

ERROR: failed to solve: alpine:3.13: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token": dial tcp [2600:1f18:2148:bc01:571f:e759:a87a:2961]:443: connect: connection refused
```

Comment: Make sure you are on a network in which the firewall is not blocking the Docker hub.